# How can I download a file automatically without click on button?

Tags: html, download

I am trying to write code that opens a clean page that downloads a file when I open it.
My problem is that I didn't find how to do it automatically. I only find this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="content/file.jpg" download > jpg link </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using a backend language, you can add this jQuery to your HTML document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a").click();

    });
</script>
```

The link will be automatically clicked as soon as the document has loaded.

Comment: No, without using a backend language such as PHP I don't know how you would do what you want without simulating a button click. I don't believe with pure HTML you can specify an automatic download

Comment: I need add this in my .php file?

Comment: Do you know how to use header() in php? My code above will work - just copy and paste into your HTML document. But if you insist on using php you will need the filename and header(), or if no filename, you will need a function such as glob()

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will works all the browsers. You can also set the auto download timing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Start Auto Download file</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('a[data-auto-download]').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
window.location = $this.attr('href');
}, 2000);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>The download should start shortly. If it doesn't, click
<a data-auto-download href="auto-download.zip">here</a>.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/07/auto-start-download-file-using.html)

Comment: The `click` answer did not work for me. But this answer did. I simplified it to `window.location = $('a').attr('href')`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Solution. But it's just a trick.
I use to do spamming in my university web-based Chat room by using this TRICK, all active chat room users will get my file :p hehe .

Download file without clicking using Pure HTML.

Syntax:

```
<iframe src="Paste your direct download link here" ></iframe>
```

For Example:

```
<iframe src="https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/98.0.2/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Installer.exe" ></iframe>
```

As the browser reloads your download will be triggered automatically.

NOTE: This won't work on images. This trick only works on videos, exe, audio, etc