# Initiate download without button

Tags: php, html

I'm a PHP newbie ... and stuck!

I would like to realize this HTML/PHP project in a single file (as opposed to using .html and .php files separately).

Basically, 3 steps are necessary.

1. upload a PDF file.
2. process the PDF file. Output is a .txt file.
3. offer the user the processed .txt file without the standard download button.

(1.) and (2.) is already properly implemented and works fine. (3.) is my problem/question. The internet offers several solutions, but all with download buttons which the user has to press to trigger download from server to local machine. I would like to write (in PHP only) code which offers the user a [Save Dialog Box](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/650x495x01_windows_standard_save_dialog.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.aIJ41TfILU.png), which permits saving the .txt file locally. Is this possible without any HTML code, hence solely by PHP?

Below the real code heavily simplified to the necessary.

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    Select PDF file to be uploaded.
    <input type = "file" name="pdffile" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "upload roster"  />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['pdffile'])) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['pdffile']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['pdffile']['size'];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'];
...
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "/home/user/pdf2txt/uploads/" . $file_name);
        $cmd = "../../pdf2txt/pdf2txt ../../pdf2txt/uploads/" . $file_name;
...
// the stdout of pdf2txt is stored in /tmp/pdffile.txt
// initiate download to user - THAT'S MY PROBLEM/QUESTION
...
?>
```

EDIT

Maybe I was too short. The project should be realized inside a WordPress page. I use a PHP plugin which permits PHP code injection. Now ... using the code of @mrid, I get ...

> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at /home/geohei/mysite/WP_TEST/wp-content/themes/blackoot-pro/header.php:12) in /home/geohei/mysite/WP_TEST/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 81

`insert-php.php` is the WordPress PHP plugin.
`blackroot` is the theme.

I understand that headers were already previously sent by the theme and I am not allowed to change them.

What can be done in such a situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a file to download in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php)

Comment: It sounds like you've already found out how to return a text file. You just have to either create two PHP files or change your single PHP file so it is made up of an if-else statement. When the `pdffile` parameter is included, process the PDF file and return the text file in the response, along with the correct headers of course. When the parameter is not included, return the HTML for the page.

Comment: Sorry ... reading your comment 5 times. I don't get why you talk about creating two PHP files (I do require everything in one file only - see EDIT above). The `pdffile` is always there, hence no need for if-else statement.

Comment: I found another possible dublicate, but no solution posted : [How can I download a file automatically without click on button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646964/how-can-i-download-a-file-automatically-without-click-on-button). It seems that in pure HTML, my download-without-click idea can't be done. In PHP, the header error (mentioned in the `EDIT` of the initial posting) prevents proper use of readfile(). I'm running out of ideas ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename) . '"');
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your suggestion and hit the next problem. I modified my initial post (after `EDIT`) to provide further details.