# How to download software after a count down without creating a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When the code given below in JavaScript runs, it starts a count down, and after completing its count down, it creates a button.

Then you can click on that button and download **something**.

I don't want that button to be created after the count down completes.

I want it to directly download that **something** after a delay, say, of 15 seconds from the time the script starts running.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 15;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");

newElement.innerHTML = "Your Course link will show in 15 seconds.";

var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function () {
  counter--;
  if (counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton);
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {
    newElement.innerHTML =
      "Your Course link will show in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258550/download-file-after-10-seconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download a file automatically without click on button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646964/how-can-i-download-a-file-automatically-without-click-on-button)

Answer (score 0):

After **clearInterval** method write your download code.

```
if (counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton);
    clearInterval(id);
    // here redirect it to download URL or call your download method
  } else {
    newElement.innerHTML =
      "Your Course link will show in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
  }
```